# Which DOS method use to convert at-sensor radiance to at-surface values in GRASS (landsat data, i.landsat.toar modul)?

Tags: grass-gis, remote-sensing, landsat, digital-image-processing, qgis-processing

I am trying to calculate **surface reflectance** values from raw Landsat DN data downloaded from GLOVIS. I have imported Landsat data in GRASS 6 with header by *i.landsat.import* and reprojected the scene into different PCS. Then I can convert DN to at-sensor radiance/reflectance values using *i.landsat.toar*.

Subsequently, I would like to convert **at-sensor values to at-surface values** (needed for further *i.topo.corr* minnaert correction because of the mountainous area). The simple metod is implemented by DOS[1-4] methods in *i.landsat.toar*. However, there are 4 DOS methods (http://grass.osgeo.org/grass65/manuals/i.landsat.toar.html):

- **DOS1:** TAUv = 1.0, TAUz = 1.0 and Esky = 0.0
- **DOS2:** TAUv = 1.0, Esky =
  0.0, and TAUz = sin(e) for all bands with maximum wave length less than 1. (i.e. bands 4-6 MSS, 1-4 TM, and 1-4 ETM+) other bands TAUz =
  1.0
- **DOS3:** TAUv = exp[-t/cos(sat_zenith)], TAUz = exp[-t/sin(e)], Esky = rayleigh
- **DOS4:** TAUv = exp[-t/cos(sat_zenith)], TAUz = exp[-t/sin(e)], Esky = PI * radiance_dark

Do you have some experiences, **which one of DOS methods is the simpliest one and provides the most reliable results in mountainous area?** 
My area of interest is varying from 800-2500 a.s.l. in Central Europe, surface about 1050 km2 (only a fraction of whole Landsat scene).

Comment: Please add also your ultimate goal to your posting: visualization or classification? Here screenshots of what I got in the southern Alps from Landsat8: http://courses.neteler.org/landsat-8-captures-trentino-november-2014/ (I also performed pansharpening).

Comment: HI markusN, my ultimate goal is the classification of bark beetle outbreak spots and forest cover identification

Comment: Hi Maria, which sensor?

Comment: Hi BillyWill, sensors are TM5, and ETM7 (I am working with landsat images from 1980 to 2014)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found Dos3 to be more relistic for Landsat 5 on the plains for green crops. No experience in other situations.

Landsat 8 will respond differently to the various correction methods, compared to L5.

I haven't used GRASS in a while, have migrated to the plugin for QGIS - see http://fromgistors.blogspot.com/

Comment: Thank you BillyWill, I have found the same in this article: Song, C., Woodcock, C. E., Seto, K. C., Lenney, M. P., & Macomber, S. A. (2000). Classification and Change Detection Using Landsat TM Data : When and How to Correct Atmospheric Effects ?, 4257(00) so I will try this one and hope that is what I am looking for :)